# Bootstrap Breakpoints - having issues

Tags: html, css, layout, responsive

I want to start off by apologizing if this has been asked before. I tried to find the answer but nothing was popping out for me. I am still very new at coding and have hit a wall in my knowledge. I appreciate any help directly or showing me in the right direction.

We are having issues with the layout on different devices. The mobile site looks good, same with the desktop. However, between 768-799px, it distorts the site and then at 800-1300px it is distorted in another way, neither looks good. I have gone through and changed all of the @media queries to try to adjust it but have had no luck. I have attached two pictures of the different issues we are experiencing.

Thank you in advance!

[Tablet view 768-799px](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KbGIu.jpg)

[Over 800px](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W5oSO.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

It is a little hard to tell exactly what is causing this without any code being posted, but flexbox is a great tool for this. https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/ is a good reference. My understanding is you want to prevent overlapping items, and how I would use this to prevent that is by putting them in separate flexbox items within the same container. There are tons of great YouTube tutorials on this topic if anything in the link is confusing.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I will look into the link as well as youtube. What parts of the code would be helpful? I'm not exactly sure what I'm looking for, and the things that I thought would make changes didn't seem to do anything. I know that is kind of vague or could be hard to answer.

Comment: I found this in the flexboxgrid.css would this help?                                       media (min-width: 300px) {
  .container {
    width: 300px;
  }
}

media (min-width: 544px) {
  .container {
    width: 510px;
  }
}
media (min-width: 768px) {
  .container {
    width: 600px;
  }
}
media (min-width: 992px) {
  .container {
    width: 800px;
  }
}
media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .container {
    width: 1200px;
  }
}

Comment: You should think about flexbox as allowing you to organize your page into groups. Do you want certain things to not overlap? Put them in the same group and assign them positions within that. The class name `.container` wont do anything, but by using the class attribute `display: flex` you will be able to make use of the flexbox toolkit